# Word Frequency in node.js (everything printed in a table)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create a table in the server containing the number of words appearing in the text file specified by an user. More in detail, the handler should do the following:
1) Check that the file is a text file.
2) Open the file specified by the user (I use the "?file=" query parameter)
3) For each word appearing in the file, count its frequency
4) Generate an HTML page showing a table with the number of times each word is found in the file.

For the part of the table and the frequency I did something but I have no idea how to do the first and second point of the list. Here is the function I implemented for part 3 and 4 (ok my function prints the letter frequency and I have to work on it but at least I have the idea). The first part is tricky. The "NodeStaticFiles" is used as the directory where I have more of my files and the second "if statement" check is the extension of the file is txt or HTML (The only extension I have to check)

```
function stats(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200,  {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    var newPath = req.url.replace(/\/file/, "NodeStaticFiles");
    var filename = newPath.split("/");
    var type=(filename[filename.length-1]).split(".");
    if(type.isFile()){
        if(type == "txt" || type == "html"){

        }
    }
    res.end();


function frequency(s) {
    if(s === undefined){
       return undefined
    } else {
        var freq = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            var character = s.charAt(i).toUpperCase();
            if (freq[character]) {
                freq[character]++;
            } else {
                freq[character] = 1;
            }
        }
  }
  return freq;
}
function table(a,dom) {
    if(dom==undefined || a==undefined){
        return undefined;
    }else {
 var table = '<table>';

 for (var x in a){
      table += '<tr><td>'+ x +'</td><td> '+ a[x] +'</td></tr>';
 }

 dom.innerHTML= table;
     }

 }


}

rh['stats'] = stats;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check out a package like gramophone